# SQL UNION ALL error

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ado

I use ADO to run SQL in excel .

I have 7 tables in  Excel workbook :2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020

Now , 2014 and 2015 have been filled data .2016 has been fill data in half .

2017,2018, 2019,2020 have no data inside as today is still 2016.

Then ,I use `from ...[$2014] UNION ALL from ...[$2014] UNION ALL from ...[$2015] UNION ALL from ...[$2016]....UNION ALL from ...[$2020]` to join all tables

Later , I find that when I look up for 2016 information ,the statistic is totally wrong . I debug for a long time .Then ,I find out the problem is 2017-2020 have no data .I add one fake row in 2017-2020 respectively so that the problem is solved .

But it is annoying that a fake row need to be added in 2017-2020 .

**Hence , any suggestions can solve the question completely ?**

---

**SQL** *(wrapped in a VBA string)*:

```sql
SELECT officer, NULL,
       SUM(IIF( isnumeric(mkt) = true AND Survey='CPI' AND Activity='FI' AND Outcome= 'C',
           Totalmin, 0 )/468),
       SUM(IIF( isnumeric(Non) = true AND Survey='CPI' AND Activity='FI' AND Outcome= 'C',
           Totalmin, 0 )/468),
       NULL, NULL,
       IIF(ISNULL(SUM(mkt)), 0, SUM(mkt)),
       Sum(Non), SUM(ICP), (SUM(mkt) + SUM(Non) + SUM(ICP)),
       NULL, NULL, NULL,
       COUNT(IIF( Survey='CPI' AND Activity='FI',
             Totalmin, NULL)),
       NULL,
       COUNT(IIF(Survey='CPI' AND Activity='FI' AND
                (Outcome ='C' OR Outcome='D'OR Outcome='O'), Totalmin, NULL )),
       NULL,
       SUM(IIF(Survey='CPI' AND Activity='FI',Totalmin, 0 )),
       NULL,
       SUM(IIF(Survey='CPI' AND Activity='FI' AND
           (Outcome ='C' OR Outcome='D'), Totalmin, 0 ))

FROM (SELECT officer, rank, year, month, day, survey, activity, 
             outcome, mkt, non, totalmin, ICP, tabledate FROM [2014$] 
      UNION ALL SELECT officer, rank, year, month, day, survey, activity,
                       outcome, mkt, non, totalmin, ICP, tabledate FROM [2015$]  
      UNION ALL SELECT officer, rank, year, month, day, survey, activity, 
                       outcome, mkt, non, totalmin, ICP, tabledate FROM [2016$]) as table3

WHERE officer IS NOT NULL 
AND officer <> '' AND officer <> ' ' 
AND tabledate >= # " & frommDate &  "# 
AND tabledate < # " & tooDate & " # 
GROUP BY officer
```

Comment: You can build the `FROM` part dynamically in a loop that goes through all existing worksheets in the Excel file

Comment: @cha But it is in SQL statement .Is it possible to run VBA loop in SQL statement?

Comment: No, I suggested running loop in VBA when you build the SQL Statement

Comment: @evabb cha suggestion was to loop through all your worksheet and only build union with populated worksheet

Comment: @Jules You mean use VBA to build the SQL that union join the table with data inside? Use `CASE` to do it `?

Comment: *Later, I find that when I look up for 2016 information, the statistic is totally wrong.*...how does 2016 info relate to 2017-2020 since this *statistic* is resolved with fake rows? Please show the expression or formula of this *statistic*.

Comment: @Parfait u mean u have made some raw data to test ? As i made a input panel that generate the report from anytime to anytime . When i select the date within 2016 , the output is totally wrong . The only resolve way is to make one fake row on 2017-2020 tables respectively .The officer name is called testing and the other columns are 0 .Hence , it can ensure the sure know that is a testing item . And now , i just want to find a way to solve the problem completely.

Comment: I am asking you for more information. It is on you to provide raw data for a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As of now, how do we know what *totally wrong* means. What statistic are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

A pseudo code from cha's comment.

```
declare SQLunion as string

for each worksheets
  if worksheet has data then SQLunion = SQLunion + "select x,y,z from " + worksheet + " union "
next

remove the last "union" from SQLunion
SQLstring = "select a, b, c from (" + SQLunion+ ") where conditions"
```